# amara and django

Tags: python, django, amara

I am trying to do webservice calls with django views using Amara library.

However anytime I do `import amara` (by simply importing it!) and call a django view with it imported, I get such errors:

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:4444/test
Django Version: 1.2.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'azula.epgdb',
 'django_extensions']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  80.                     response = middleware_method(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  58.                     _is_valid_path("%s/" % request.path_info, urlconf)):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in _is_valid_path
  143.         urlresolvers.resolve(path, urlconf)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  301.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  216.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  123.             return self.callback, args, kwargs
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  129.             self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  124.         result = func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  56.                 lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)
File "/home/uluc/azula/epgdb/views.py" in <module>
  4. from azula.epgdb.utils import EventSet
File "/home/uluc/azula/epgdb/utils.py" in <module>
  6. import amara
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/amara/__init__.py" in <module>
  11. import binderytools
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/amara/binderytools.py" in <module>
  13. from Ft.Xml import InputSource
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/InputSource.py" in <module>
  355. DefaultFactory = InputSourceFactory(catalog=GetDefaultCatalog())
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Catalog.py" in GetDefaultCatalog
  579.                 catalog = Catalog(uri, quiet)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Catalog.py" in __init__
  95.             self._parseXmlCat(data)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Catalog.py" in _parseXmlCat
  372.         from Ft.Xml.Sax import CreateParser
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Sax.py" in <module>
  242. class SaxPrinter(ContentHandler):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Sax.py" in SaxPrinter
  247.     def __init__(self, printer=XmlPrinter(sys.stdout, 'utf-8')):
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/Ft/Xml/Lib/XmlPrinter.py" in __init__
  39.         self.stream = sw = cStreamWriter.StreamWriter(stream, encoding)

Exception Type: TypeError at /test
Exception Value: argument must have 'write' attribute
```

How can this be solved ? I tried this under either Debian Lenny & Ubuntu 10.04 yet via Django SVN version and Amara 1

I am suspicious of some character encoding problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting "WSGIRestrictStdout Off" to my apache fixed the issue as said in [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showpost.php?p=225788&postcount=3).

Comment: I don't really see that as a fix though. It should not be trying to access `sys.stdout` unless it has a valid reason to.